# What is the difference between `*a =` and `= *a`?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, lvalue, rvalue

In following function,

```c
void swap(int * a, int * b) {
    int t;
     t = *a; // = *a
    *a = *b; // a* =
    *b =  t;
}
```

What is the difference between `= *a` and `*a =`?

I've heard that the `*` operator in `= *a` is a de-referencing(or in-directing) operator which *fetches(?)* that value from the pointer.

Then, what is the actual meaning of `*a =`?

---

Yesterday, the day I asked this question, I explained about pointers to my colleague whose major field has nothing to do with pointers.

I quickly typed a source code like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap1(int a , int b) {
    int t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}

void swap2(int * a, int * b) {
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    swap1(a, b);
    swap2(&a, &b);
}
```

I was even proud of myself for remembering things imprinted on my brain in 1996. (I've been with Java for almost 20 years.)
I used a bunch of `printf`s with `%d`s and `%p`s to show her what was happening.

Then I made **a terrible mistake**. I *declared*.

> 포인터 변수 앞에 **별**을 붙이면 값을 가져온다는 뜻이에요.
>
> When you attach a **STAR** in front of a pointer variable, that means you fetches(retrieves) the value.

Well that could be applied to following statement.

```
int t = *a;
```

Which simply can be said,

```
int t = 10;
```

The big problem I faced came from the second statement.

```
*a = *b; // 10 = 20?
```

The root evil is that I didn't try to explain about the ***[dereference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator)*** or I didn't ask to myself of being aware of the meaning of a ***별(star)***.

Here is what people would say.

> for `= *a`,
>
> ***the actual value*** at the address denoted by `a` is assigned to the left side.
>
> for `*a =`
>
> the value of the right side is ***stored in the address*** denoted by `a`.

That's what I'm confusing of. And that's why I should re-think about the meaning of `de-referencing'.

Thanks for answers.

---

Oh I think this problem is going deeper to the concepts of `lvalue`s and `rvalue`s.

Comment: It seems to be time again for Binky: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
t = *a;
```

the pointer `a` is dereferenced and this value is assigned to `t` whereas here:

```
*a = *b;
```

both `b` and `a` are dereferenced and the value of `*b` is stored in the address `a`.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is reading from the memory `a` is pointing to. The second one is writing to that memory.

This is no different from `x =` and `= x` except that you do not access the variable directly but the object it is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

It has no relation with '=' operator .It(* operator) just means value at 'a's address.So

```
t = *a;   assigns value at address a to t
*a = *b;  assigns b's value in place of value at address a
*b =  t;  assigns t to b's value
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a pointer here, pointing to an int.

`*a` retrieves the integer value stored at memory pointed to by `a`. When you say `*a = <some value>`, assuming `<some value>` to be an `int`, `<some value>` gets stored at memory location pointed to by `a`.

`*a = *b` ==> Here b is again an int pointer, so integer value pointed to by `b` is read and written to memory location pointed to by `a`.

Answer (score 1):

> I've heard that the * operator in = *a is a de-referencing(or in-directing) operator which fetches(?)

In fact fetch happens when you dereference a pointer with operator `*` alone. Hence assignment `=` operator doesn't involve in dereferencing perhaps assigning the dereferenced value to LHS.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between = *a and *a =?

Well... look at this code:

```
int x;
t = x;
x = t;
```

If you have any plain variable `int x;` then you can read from it and write to it. That's the difference between your two lines as well.

`*` is the "contents of" operator. If `a` is a pointer to `int`, then `*a` simply means that you can use the contents of that variable as if it had been a plain int variable. And just like any variable you can either read or write to it.